# Checking if user is authenticated in Phoenix templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

I am working on a **phoenix application**. The authentication part is implemented with [`Guardian`](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian).

Like a typical web site, the app has a header, footer, and a sidebar. These are static pages in the layout folder.

tree view

`-lib
 |--admin_app_web
   |--templates
      |--layouts
         |--app.html.eex
         |--header.html.eex
         |--sidebar.html.eex
         |--main.html.eex`

The `app.html.eex` looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "header.html", conn: @conn%>
    <%= render "flash.html", conn: @conn%>
    <%= render "main.html", assigns %>
    <%=# render "footer.html" %>
      <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`main.html.eex` is on these lines

```
<main role="main" class="row my-3">
  <div class="col-2">
    <%= render "sidebar.html" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
  </div>
</main>
```

**I want to render the `sidebar.html.eex` only if `user` is `authenticated`, how to achieve this**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a user is authenticated using `Guardian.Plug.authenticated?/2` and use `if` to selectively render the sidebar template.

```
<div class="col-2">
  <%= if Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(@conn, []), do: render("sidebar.html") %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dogbert for the prompt reply.